# Is it possible to do sensitivity analysis

Tags: r

I have obtained following equation from power model after log transformation.

```
 logy = 3.651 + 0.648*logind1 + 0.915*logind2
```

I want to do sensitivity analysis and create a graph
where x axis is first independent variable (ind1),
y axis is y where I want to plot different curvatures of 2nd independent value
like following photo.

Value on the plot should not be in log scale.

I am not sure if R can be used for this purpose.

This is my data in original value:

```
df <- data.frame(y, ind1, Ind2)
dput(head(df))

 structure(list(y = c(17.5460928, 15.09292512, 404.6266803, 509.8268418, 
 22.29624608, 27.62826976), ind1 = c(0.003739281, 0.003473227, 
 0.096486361, 0.124097819, 0.005281017, 0.005089576), Ind2 = c(0.20708766, 
 0.216378894, 0.628712871, 0.505681818, 0.318622945, 0.245192308
 )), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

thank you so much!

Comment: There is no photo on the explanation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you have something like this in mind?

```
# Vector of values over which to perform the analysis.
vec.pars <- c(0.1, 0.3, 0.6)

# The function for calculating Y.
calcY <- function(x, ind1) {
  3.651 + 0.648 * ind1 + 0.915 * x
}
# Vectorized version. This enables us to apply the above function
# to a vector of values at the same time.
calcY <- Vectorize(FUN = calcY, vectorize.args = "x", SIMPLIFY = FALSE)

# Construct the output
vec.y <- calcY(x = vec.pars, ind1 = df$ind1)
xy <- data.frame(y = do.call(c, vec.y))
xy$ind1 <- rep(df$ind1, times = length(vec.y))
xy$ind2 <- rep(vec.pars, each = nrow(df))

ggplot(xy, aes(x = ind1, y = y, color = as.factor(ind2))) +
  theme_bw() +
  geom_line()
```

[image]

Comment: @ Roman Lustrik. woow, it looks amazing. it is exactly what I want. Thank you so much.

Comment: I have a question about it. Variable of the equation is in logarithm (logy = 3.651 + 0.648*logind1 + 0.915*logind2). Here I posted my original data before log transforming which was done to linearize the data. So do you think I should use log transformed values of ind1 and ind2 or just directly use original value without nonlinearizing.

Comment: @M.Amor that sounds like a question for your local statistician.

Comment: Can we add original data on the graph together with this lines?

Comment: @M.Amor can you be more specific - what original data?

Comment: I mean data points and prediction line that extracted from data as well